# Why is my Core i5 9400F not throttling back to stock 2.9GHz?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard

My computer is a new build. Just added the motherboard and CPU a week ago. Motherboard is a new Gigabyte Z390 UD. The CPU is a new Intel Core i5 9400F. RAM is existing Kingston HyperX Fury DDR4 2400 dual channel 8GB (2 x 4GB). The graphics card is existing Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

With my BIOS set to defaults and almost everything on Auto, my Core i5 runs continuously at full speed (3.9GHz). Using CPU-Z shows processor speed fluctuating between 3.9GHz and 4.0GHz. It never drops to stock 2.9GHz. I've tried changing Auto to enabled for C1E, EIST, Energy Efficient Turbo, CPU Thermal Monitor, Intel Speedshift Tech., but it still runs at full speed. Task Manager is showing system idle, but it's still running at full speed.

I can get it to run at stock 2.9GHz by disabling Enhanced Multi Core, but if I do that I obviously will never get full CPU speed. Do you have any ideas?

Windows 10 system idle:

[image: Windows 10 system idle]

Comment: Why are you concerned by the behavior you have witnessed?

Comment: I've got a cpu that should throttle back to stock 2.9GHz, and it doesn't at the moment. The benefits of having that option are mainly reduced power consumption and less wear on the cpu. Probably more reasons, but that's mainly why I want the problem sorted.

Comment: This a new problem or has it always existed?

Comment: it's a new build. Just added mainboard and cpu a week ago.

Comment: my previous i5 worked as it should. Throttled back on system idle.

Comment: Your previous processor and motherboard was different hardware.

Comment: Do you have the APP Center (Gigabyte software) installed?

Comment: yes, I do have APP Center installed. Just so you know, the cpu is a i5 9400F, and is NOT able to be overclocked. So, clock ratio settings etc are not possible.

Comment: It’s not supported by Intel but motherboards like you purchased have ways around it.  I would try and uninstall it, the software supports something called Game Boost, which is suspiciously named.

Comment: What is your Windows power plan set to? If it is set to High Performance then switch to Balanced. High performance will keep the CPU pegged at its highest speed.

Comment: Was set to High Performance, so switched to Balanced. It's now working as it should. Thanks for the help everyone :)